# Issue with the cache manifest "prefer-online" setting

Tags: html, http

When setting the **prefer-online** setting I expect the browser to request the page at every refresh of the browser, but it is not the case.

Here is my manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST

SETTINGS:
prefer-online

NETWORK:
*
```

Yet when I refresh the browser it only requests the manifest to the server. It only requests the page when I update the  manifest ...

And there is no headers (expires or max-age) set on the page.

(tested on chrome & firefox)

NB: When updating the manifest, the browser re downloads the assets, but still displays the old version ... It is only on the next load that the browser uses the new assets. Why ?

Comment: Same issue here. The master entities should be redownloaded automatically if possible but it seems not to work at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the AppCache manifest is for, since you want to bypass the cache and just use the network. Keep in mind that the regular caching might still apply, regardless of the AppCache manifest, so check the `Expires`, `Last-Modified` and similar headers.

As for your question:

> NB: When updating the manifest, the browser re downloads the assets, but still displays the old version ... It is only on the next load that the browser uses the new assets. Why ?

This is because the user agent will immediately use the latest cached version of your assets, then start checking the linked resources listed in the manifest for updates. When the user agent detects that the manifest has changed, and thus it has to check for updates, it will fire a `checking` event.

When the update checking process has finished (and it might take a long time, if you have lots of resources) it will fire an `updateready` event. Only the resources fetched *after* this event will be the fresh new ones (that's why it's usually adviceable to use `window.applicationCache.swapCache()` to tell the browser to swap the old cache for the new for the next page load, or simply reload the page and be done with it).

You will find more detailed explanations about these topics here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Regarding "This is because the user agent will immediately use the latest cached version of your assets": This should not be true when using the "prefer-online" SETTINGS flag.